# Adding alert button to cart page in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, alert, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a button under the product name in the cart page for each item which I did, but my alert isn't showing when the button is clicked

```
function request_button( $product_title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $_request = '<div class="request-button"><button type="button" value="save_request" onclick="myFunction()">Request tailormeasurement</button></div>';
    return $product_title. '<br/>' . $_request;
    if(!$item[$_request]){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {
                alert("You have requested tailor measurement");
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'request_button' , 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You write **return** so the function will exit and not continue the rest of code in this function, the if statement that contains  tag will not rendered

try use echo or print instead of return here